# Node.js installation on Debian 6

Tags: ssh, debian, apt, node.js

I used to use [this method](http://vorb.de/log/2012/02/node-and-npm-on-debian.html) for node.js installation on Debian, since it was easy and everything worked fine. Even with multiple users.

Since version 0.6.18~dfsg1-1 of the [sid package](http://packages.debian.org/sid/nodejs), installation removes openssh-server. But I need OpenSSH to connect to my server.

Is there any possibility to install Node.js via APT or do I have to compile it manually?

This is my APT preferences file:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 800

Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 650

Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 600
```

Comment: can you show your apt/preferences file?

Comment: Okay. Does it help?

Comment: yeah, try lowering unstable pin priority to lower than 500.
Or try aptitude install nodejs/unstable

Comment: oh, I see that nodejs/sid depends on  libc6 >= 2.13-28. That means it is not useful in squeeze.
You will need to compile your own backported version of NodeJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used the [technique described on the nodejs wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation).

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.18/node-v0.6.18.tar.gz
tar -zxf node-v0.6.18.tar.gz
cd node-v0.6.18
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

This was not the solution I wanted, but it solves my problem.

Answer (score -2):

[This](http://sindro.me/2011/9/12/install-node-js-via-apt-on-debian-squeeze) seems to be useful in your case

Comment: In the case of links offsite, it's usually more useful to summarise the answer presented in the link (obviously, don't just copy and paste) in case the linked to website vanishes, at which point there's no detail in your answer to help with the question.

Comment: This technique didn't help. I wanted to build the deps, but there’s no sufficient version of libv8 available at the moment.